# How to show the correct date in format of datepicker in Angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a Angular 8 application. And I am using the Datepicker of material.

But if I fill in a date an call the get api call:

```
  searchFor(filterRegistration: FilterByRegistrationDTO) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    console.log(
      this.participantService.filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, "Invited", this.startDate.toString()).subscribe(result => {       
        console.log(this.startDate.toString());
        console.log(result);
      })
    );
```

And the template looks like this:

```
    <div>
      <mat-form-field  class="search-field-input">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="start datum" [(ngModel)]="startDate"  />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

So on the server side the date will be show as: jjjj-MM-dd.

But on the client side the date has to been shown as: dd-MM-jjjj.

But so if I call the api call:

```
console.log(
      this.participantService.filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, "Invited", this.startDate.toString()).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(this.startDate.toString());
        console.log(result);
      })
    );
```

Then I will get this error:

```
core.js:12584 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "https://dev-engine.mijnhep.nl/api/medical/organisa…GMT%2B0200%20(Central%20European%20Summer%20Time)", ok: false, …}
error:
Start: ["The value 'Mon Oct 07 2019 12:58:46 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)' is not valid for Start."]
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://dev-/api/medical/organisation/1/Participant/filter-by-registration?Filter=Invited&Start=Mon%20Oct%2007%202019%2012:58:46%20GMT%2B0200%20(Central%20European%20Summer%20Time): 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
url: "/api/medical/organisation/1/Participant/filter-by-registration?Filter=Invited&Start=Mon%20Oct%2007%202019%2012:58:46%20GMT%2B0200%20(Central%20European%20Summer%20Time)"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

So my question is. how to fill in the correct date format on the client side. So that it will not thrown an error?

Thank you

Comment: you could use javascript to parse the formats or use a library like moment.js or date functions to easily wrap it for you.

Comment: [RTFD](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)

Comment: thank you. But an example would be nice

Comment: Why not format the submitted date?? instead of this.startDate.toString() format the date correctly?

Comment: Yes, oke. But format?? can you give example? will be nice

Comment: I try like this: this.startDate.toString('jjj-mm-dd')

Comment: With moment it would be moment(this.startDate).format('someting that works here')

Comment: But can you show in the code I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iso date format using `JSON.stringify(yourDate)`

then on server side just use this value.

Otherwise, on client side, you can use `moment(yourDate).format('L');`

https://momentjs.com/

In your code, it would be:

```
this.participantService.filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, "Invited", JSON.stringify(this.startDate))
```

or

```
this.participantService.filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, "Invited", moment(yourDate).format('L'))
```